# MySQL get duplicate(unique) rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table Person(id, email, phone, firstName) where email and phone should be unique. If I have for example (1, "test@mail.com", null, "test") and i try to add new row with same data this will cause problem because of the unique column email. Is it possible to understand which column cause duplicate problem email or phone (in this situation query should return email column).

Comment: the exception message tells you which column is violating the unique constrait

Comment: I think that if you use unique constraints and name the constraint, then MySQL will return the name of the violated constraint.

Comment: It`s returned in the exception but is it possible to be return as return value of the query ?

Comment: You could just do a SELECT first to see if the email/phone already exists.  Error handling shouldn't be a form of control flow.

Comment: @user5783530 . . . The query returns an error/exception.  You need to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting Data from another table you can join both tables first to find all rows that would violate your Unique Constraint.

```
Select A.* 
FROM Data_That_Could_Violate_Your_Constraint A
INNER JOIN Person B
ON(A.phone=B.phone or A.firstName = B.firstName)
```

This will return all records that would violate your Constraint on insert since they share the same value in `phone`, `firstName`or both.